# Delete mobile data using Root

Tags: rooting, mobile-data

I'm looking for the right Android files I can delete to completely disable mobile data

I have an open root (Android 4.1.2)

I'm not looking to do using APN or other solutions, but by deleting the appropriate files

I'd be happy to get help, or appropriate links to look at.

I have already searched Google and found no suitable answer

Comment: Only if you have backup of /system and possibility of restoring it in case it is soft bricked: each service in android os is like an app, just playing around with, delete some apks from /system/app. Maybe CarrierConfig.apk or SettingsProvider.apk

Comment: delete `/system/etc/apns-conf.xml`

Comment: and /system/app/telephony