# How to permanenlty disable mobile data by renaming or editing files or directories on rooted-device?

Tags: root-access, file-system, mobile-data, internet, apn

Yes, I read the answers to the question by the link [Disable mobile data permanently](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174152/302598) but I'm interested in a solution related with directories and files on rooted-device and not in using an application or setting(s).

I also read the comments to the question [Delete mobile data using Root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212209/302598) but the deleting `/system/etc/apns-conf.xml` dosn't help and I don't have the `/system/app/telephony` as well as `/system/CarrierConfig.apk` and `/system/SettingsProvider.apk`, maybe because I use Android 4.0.4 (?).

I know that to disable Wi-Fi it's enough to obtain root permissions and rename the folder `/wifi` inside of the `/etc` to another e.g. `/wif`. Can we do something like that to permanenlty disable also mobile data for example by renaming some directories or files or edit some file(s)?

Comment: So in the end telephony and SMS should work but no data connection, right? What about MMS (usually requires an WAP or mobile data connection)?

Comment: @Robert Yes, I meant mobile Internet only. MMS doesn't matter

Comment: @Robert is there a way or at least a link where I can read about?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't help you on that topic because I simply don't know a way how to do so.